# RelatedObjectDoesNOTExist-Edit profile

Tags: django-views

Django==1.10.5. I have a problem RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
Views.py:

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)

    if user_form.is_valid():
        # Create a new user object but avoid saving it yet
        new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
        # Set the chosen password
        new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
        # Save the User object
        new_user.save()
        # Create the user profile
        profile = Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)
        return render(request,
                      'account/register_done.html',
                      {'new_user': new_user})
else:
    user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'user_form': user_form})
```

and

```
@login_required
def edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user,
                                 data=request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile,
                                       data=request.POST,
                                       files=request.FILES)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
    else:
       user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
       profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    return render(request, 'account/edit.html', {'user_form': user_form,
                                             'profile_form': profile_form})
```

The problem is that:
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile)

Comment: django.db.models.fields.related.descriptors.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist. User has no profile-profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile)

Comment: solved the question

Comment: Post your own solution as an answer, a comment is not intended for this matter and will easily skipped by others with your similar problem

Answer (score 3):

I have similar experience working on this particular exercise.
The error is coming right from code below

Profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)

We are trying to get "request.user.profile" not realizing "User" in the model doesn't have a "profile" but a Profile has a"User" . Therefore a better way to get the "profile":

```
        profile = Profile(user=request.user)
```

Hence your edit method should look close to this:

```
@login_required
def edit(request):

    profile = Profile(user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user,data=request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=profile,
                       data=request.POST,
                       files=request.FILES)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Profile updated successfully')
    else:
        messages.success(request, 'Error updating your profile')
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=profile)
    return render(request,
                  'accounts/edit.html',
                  {'user_form': user_form,
                  'profile_form': profile_form})
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to answer this question, this code is a snippet from the `Django By Example` book from the project `Building a Social Website`.

I encountered the same error when I clicked on the `edit your profile` link in the dashboard.

So, to solve this error, if you are logged in as a superuser, then go to the admin site of your project (url: `localhost/admin/`) and then under the `Account` heading, click on `Profiles` and click the `Add profile` link on the top right corner. Select the user from the dropdown, add the profile details and click `save`.

Now going back to the dashboard and clicking the `edit your profile` link should display the desired view.

Comment: Yes. The author says this in the book. "You should create a Profile object manually using the administration site for the users you created before."

Answer (score -2):

I tried another alternative this scenario is that when we update our code we have some users that registered but not have a profile. I deleted the users and in admin and signed up with account it worked

but you will have a problem when logging with facebook

Comment: This doesn't address the question which is being asked here.