# Django extending user with userprofile (error: User has no profile.)

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-registration

[image]someone can told me, why this code don't working?
I'm trying to create a registration form for users.

> I'm getting an error
>
> "RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /signup/client/2/ User has no profile."

views.py

```
if request.POST:
            user_form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
            profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
            if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
                user = user_form.save()
                user.profile.city="WW"
                user.profile.phone="32323"
                user.profile.save()
```

forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ( 'city', 'phone')
```

html file

```
  <h2>Sign up</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ user_form.as_p }}
    {{ profile_form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
```

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.TextField(max_length = 50)
    phone = models.TextField(max_length = 12)
```

Comment: This answer by Yoshita Arora solved it for me.
Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43766121/869977)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `profile`, it does not get created when you save `user_form`

```
        user_form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            Profile.objects.create(**{
                 'city':"WW", 'phone': '32323', 'user': user
            })
            # ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the following line to the script:

```
profile = Profile.objects.create(user=request.user)
```

Comment: Welcome! Is this an answer or a comment to Bear Brown? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this code is referred from 'Django by Examples'. If so, Go to your application admin Site and add a profile manually under profile account and run the server again. This will solve the issue.

Comment: No, this is my own code. Adding a profile manually? Rather, it should be created automatically.

Comment: In your model.py , you are creating profiles based on the User model and OnetoOneField. So, you will have to create profiles from your admin site.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest thing to do here while in the development is:

1. in the terminal create another superuser -$ python manage.py createsuperuser
2. login in the admin page with the new credentials
3. Delete the old admin or any user that may have been created before the userprofile
   models were created

Comment: This is a suggestion on how to deal with DB inconsistencies, not an answer to the question. Please add this kind of suggestions as comment instead of as answers.